# Converting WPF app as Class library

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dll

I developed a WPF code that suppose to take perimeters from main app and draw antenna pattern in 3d. i used WPF because i found it easy for me to draw 3d shape.

For starting point i created a WPF application project and used a equation of curve to draw a shape in 3d. But my main app was old and written in VB. Now i stuck at a point to convert my WPF app project as library that take some constant values from mian program (in VB) and approximate a shape in 3d.

Question:

Is there any way i can use my WPF app project to convert it to a class lib or something that can be used in VB?

(OR)

I have to write new code for VB class lib?

AND also

The main thing is i also used an external library (3Dtools.dll) in WPF, will it include the class library that is to be created(i mean, can a .dll be created which is already using an external .dll )

I have no strong programing background and couldn't find help regarding this problem. Any link or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: you can use your WPF Application as a reference from your VB application. You don't have to rewrite your C# code in VB.

Comment: The thing is the app is made on the base of equation it did not ask for perimeters or values(integers) to process on them, if i had to pass some integers don't you think it should be a class lib

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want. Could you be more specific please?